# Informatica default value - best practice for easy debugging?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I’m debugging a legacy informatica process, curious to know what’s the best convention for default value?

For now I’m changing the default

From :  ERROR('transformation error') - this is very generic, not useful to track where the error came from.

To : ERROR('mapOD_LOAD_HIST/EXP_load_hist_inpsz.o_REPORTID')   see screenshot below.

Is there an informatica shortcut to automatically include the mappingName/transformationName.fieldName. That way I won’t need to go to every field and type the exact map/trans/field.

[image]

Comment: Is your target table getting populated from multiple sessions? Otherwise where is the point of having mapping name in the information?

Comment: yes different columns in the target gets updated by different sessions (legacy - trying to make it easily debuggable so that I can potentially depricate/replace this with a java program)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you ask, but why not just using a clipboard history saving , retrieving program such as [ArsClip](http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/97/) ?

Been using it for several years and it is a time saver for any coding on Windows ...

Another speed up would be using wf export 
    pmrep.exe connect -r REPO_NAME -d DOMAIN_NAME -n USER -s Native -x PASS
    pmrep.exe objectexport -n wf_name -f foldername -o workflow -s -b -r -u wf_name.XML

open the file with the notepad++ with the XPatherized plugin : search for the /POWERMART/REPOSITORY/FOLDER/MAPPING/TRANSFORMATION/TRANSFORMFIELD[../@NAME='ExpressionName']

any xml search and replace generic would be hightly appreaciate ...